# Dealing with infs in Seq2Seq Trainer

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nan, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am trying to fine tune a hugging face model onto a Shell Code dataset (https://huggingface.co/datasets/SoLID/shellcode_i_a32)

The training code is a basic hugging face trainer method but we keep running into nan/inf issues

```py
from transformers import PreTrainedTokenizerFast

tokenizer = PreTrainedTokenizerFast(tokenizer_file="tkn1.json", padding_side="right") 
special_tokens={'pad_token': "[PAD]"}

tokenizer.add_special_tokens(special_tokens)

#  token_wrap = PreTrainedTokenizer()
data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer=tokenizer, model=model)

training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./results",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    lr_scheduler_type = "cosine",
    weight_decay=0.01,
    save_total_limit=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=128,
    num_train_epochs=5,
    warmup_ratio=0.06,
    learning_rate=1.0e-04,
    # fp16=True,
    debug=["underflow_overflow"]
)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["test"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["test"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=data_collator,
)
# trainer.train()
# print(tokenizer.)
trainer.train()
# eval_loss = trainer.evaluate()
# print(f">>> Perplexity: {math.exp(eval_loss['eval_loss']):.2f}")
```

The outputs look like -

```
You're using a PreTrainedTokenizerFast tokenizer. Please note that with a fast tokenizer, using the `__call__` method is faster than using a method to encode the text followed by a call to the `pad` method to get a padded encoding.


Detected inf/nan during batch_number=0
Last 1 forward frames:
abs min  abs max  metadata
                  shared Embedding
5.42e-06 2.04e+04 weight
0.00e+00 1.46e+03 input[0]
1.56e-03 2.04e+04 output



---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-120-ff4a54906908> in <module>
     33 # trainer.train()
     34 # print(tokenizer.)
---> 35 trainer.train()
     36 # eval_loss = trainer.evaluate()
     37 # print(f">>> Perplexity: {math.exp(eval_loss['eval_loss']):.2f}")

9 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/transformers/debug_utils.py in forward_hook(self, module, input, output)
    278 
    279             # now we can abort, as it's pointless to continue running
--> 280             raise ValueError(
    281                 "DebugUnderflowOverflow: inf/nan detected, aborting as there is no point running further. "
    282                 "Please scroll up above this traceback to see the activation values prior to this event."

ValueError: DebugUnderflowOverflow: inf/nan detected, aborting as there is no point running further. Please scroll up above this traceback to see the activation values prior to this event.
```

The very first layer seems to start throwing inf/nans when we start training and doesn't go much beyond that

We have tried tweaking our training arguments but have hit a brick wall here. Any help appreciated!